# BrowserStack localhost doesn't exist

Tags: localhost, local, browserstack

I'm trying to get local BrowserStack testing working. I downloaded the CLI tool into c:\BrowserStack. When I create a command prompt in that directory and enter `BrowserStackLocal.exe -f , localhost`, I get  `**** Error! localhost doesn't exist!`. I know that IIS is up and running, because I have launched just localhost prior to doing this and I'm sitting there looking at it. All documentation I've seen assumes that this will "just work" and so doesn't provide any troubleshooting steps other than making sure the server is running.

My ultimate goal is to get it running with a port number, but I got the same error and I'm trying to back up to where I can get something that works.

I've also tried running command prompt as an administrator and using `http:// localhost` as the last argument (I didn't expect that to work, and it didn't). Note that space in there is just because stackexchange doesn't like the path I used--it's not actually in what I really entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Browserstack docs for PC are wrong. The command to issue from the command prompt isn't BrowserStackLocal.exe, but just BrowserStack (no exe). After that, it's much easier to use the site notation than pointing at localhost + port.